# Synonym [jaxb2] for [jaxb]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[jaxb2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaxb2) should be a synonym to [jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaxb).

The difference between tags is insignificant. [jaxb2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaxb2) points to the 2.x version of JAXB, but nowadays almost noone uses other versions. The only other version is 1.x which is long obsolete. So specifying the version in the tag is not really necessary. An even counterprodactivce. I often notice that some questions are tagged with [jaxb2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaxb2) only and are not noticed by users following [jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaxb).

Comment: The synonym is already proposed.  Just invite other hi-rep [jaxb] users to vote for it by posting a link to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jaxb/synonyms) as a comment on one of their posts.

Answer (score 1):

Skaffman proposed this synonym, at this very moment, 8 years ago (Sep 25 '10 at 14:07). But it was not approved. I approved it and it has now been synonymized.

The tags were synonymized in the same way as was originally proposed, i.e:

jaxb × 9756 ← jaxb2 × 794